# Truck Routing and Toll Cost Calculation for Romania

Tags: here-api

I have the following request :

```
https://tce.cit.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&departure=now&avoidseasonalclosures=true&cost_optimize=1&metricsystem=metric&truckRestrictionPenalty=soft&driver_cost=15&vehicle_cost=0.85&currency=EUR&vehicletype=diesel,24&truckType=tractorTruck&tollVehicleType=3&hybrid=0&emissionType=6&passengersCount=1&commercial=1&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=3&tiresCount=12&height=4.0m&width=2.50m&length=16.5m&heightAbove1stAxle=3.5m&trailerHeight=4.0m&vehicleWeight=12.0t&limitedWeight=40.0t&weightPerAxle=10.0t&maneuverAttributes=none&combineChange=true&routeAttributes=none,no,wp,lg&legAttributes=none,li,sh&linkAttributes=none,fl,le&detail=1&alternatives=1&rollup=none,total,country&jsonattributes=41&waypoint0=geo!stopOver!47.05185,21.93873;;6,7,2,8,9,10&waypoint1=geo!stopOver!44.85142,24.87989;;6,7,2,8,9,10&app_id=APPID&app_code=APPCODE
```

The resulting route is a bad one. 
The restrictions for trucks are not there on the real roads. 
The correct route is given by the following request :

```
https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=APPID&app_code=APPCODE&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&departure=now&avoidseasonalclosures=true&metricsystem=metric&truckRestrictionPenalty=soft&trailersCount=1&height=4.0&width=2.50&length=16.5&limitedWeight=40.0&weightPerAxle=10.0&maneuverAttributes=none&combineChange=true&routeattributes=none,no,wp,lg,summary&linkattributes=none,fl,le&legattributes=none,li,sh&detail=1&alternatives=1&jsonattributes=41&waypoint0=geo!stopOver!47.05185,21.93873;;6,7,2,8,9,10&waypoint1=geo!stopOver!44.85142,24.87989;;6,7,2,8,9,10
```

Also the toll cost returned by both requests are wrong. 
The returned value for one day is 11 RON and the amount in target currency is 2.36 EUR. 
The correct value for one day is 11 EUR. 
The bridge costs are correct.

Where can i report problems regarding the toll cost calculation and the truck restrictions ? 
There is a request to get the list of truck restrictions on a route ? 
The toll costs values are returned with VAT or without VAT. Can i get both values ? (with and without VAT)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a here-api support request.

Comment: Well, i was directed here from Here to ask questions about here-api.

Comment: Unfortunately there are some companies that just send their users here without any guidance on what question can be asked here and which can't - thus resulting in bad user experience. Nevertheless, this is not here.com and all questions must follow stackoverflow's rules - see [help/on-topic].

Comment: The toll costs currencies are displayed correctly now. Please comment if you still see issues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50911406/toll-cost-vat-here-api

Answer (score 0):

The toll costs currencies are displayed correctly now. Please comment if you still see issues. `stackoverflow.com/questions/50911406/toll-cost-vat-here-api`