# Toll Cost VAT HERE API

Tags: here-api

I have two routes in Italy.

Gad-Oulx - Genova. The toll cost returned is 58.70 EUR without VAT.

```
https://tce.cit.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&departure=now&avoidseasonalclosures=true&cost_optimize=1&metricsystem=metric&truckRestrictionPenalty=soft&driver_cost=15&vehicle_cost=0.85&currency=EUR&vehicletype=diesel,24&truckType=tractorTruck&tollVehicleType=3&hybrid=0&emissionType=6&passengersCount=1&commercial=1&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=3&tiresCount=12&height=4.0m&width=2.50m&length=16.5m&heightAbove1stAxle=3.5m&trailerHeight=4.0m&vehicleWeight=12.0t&limitedWeight=40.0t&weightPerAxle=10.0t&maneuverAttributes=none&combineChange=true&routeAttributes=none,no,wp,lg&legAttributes=none,li,sh&linkAttributes=none,fl,le&detail=1&alternatives=1&rollup=none,total,country&jsonattributes=41&waypoint0=geo!stopOver!45.04354,6.84545;;6,7,2,8,9,10&waypoint1=geo!stopOver!44.4104,8.93898;;6,7,2,8,9,10&app_id=APPID&app_code=APPCODE
```

Brennero - Bologna. The toll cost returned is 63.10 EUR with VAT.

```
https://tce.cit.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&departure=now&avoidseasonalclosures=true&cost_optimize=1&metricsystem=metric&truckRestrictionPenalty=soft&driver_cost=15&vehicle_cost=0.85&currency=EUR&vehicletype=diesel,24&truckType=tractorTruck&tollVehicleType=3&hybrid=0&emissionType=6&passengersCount=1&commercial=1&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerNumberAxles=3&tiresCount=12&height=4.0m&width=2.50m&length=16.5m&heightAbove1stAxle=3.5m&trailerHeight=4.0m&vehicleWeight=12.0t&limitedWeight=40.0t&weightPerAxle=10.0t&maneuverAttributes=none&combineChange=true&routeAttributes=none,no,wp,lg&legAttributes=none,li,sh&linkAttributes=none,fl,le&detail=1&alternatives=1&rollup=none,total,country&jsonattributes=41&waypoint0=geo!stopOver!47.00142,11.50413;;6,7,2,8,9,10&waypoint1=geo!stopOver!44.50483,11.34519;;6,7,2,8,9,10&app_id=APPID&app_code=APPCODE
```

There is a way to get a flag to determine if the returned value contains or not the VAT ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It totally depends on the region whether VAT is applied or not. Here toll costs represents the total toll amount and do not provide information on whether vat is inclusive.